# Karate not able to remove inner json attribute from json object

Tags: karate

I'm using almost latest karate versions (karate-core, karate-junit5 versioned 1.3.0 and karate-archetype 1.4.0.RC3), I read below json data from file and want to remove *structureInfo* property from same. The json field i want to remove has nested with other json fields as listed below:

**structureInfo** has **strucureComponent, properties, fields** etc in it

I tried, with delete  and remove commands
either of delete command or remove command did not work in this **specific case** where i have nested json objects

```
    * def showJson = read('classpath:Data/show.json')   # read the json from file
    * if(true) delete showJson['body.structureInfo']
    * if(true) delete showJson['showJsonbody.structureInfo']
            
**Data in json file:**
        {
      "header": {
        "method": "GET",
        "response": {
          "type": "basic",
          "status": "success"
        },
        "source": "#present"
      },
      "session": "abc",
      "body": {
        "session": {
          "structuralComponent": {
            "id": 2000,
            "type": "tabs",
            "orderSeq": 0,
            "properties8i": {
            }
          }
        },
        *"structureInfo": {
          "structureComponent": {
            "id": 2000,
            "type": "tabs",
            "orderSeq": 0,
            "properties": {
            },
            "fields": [
              {
                "id": 2001,
                "label": "#regex General[ a-zA-Z0-9!@#$%^&*()]+",
                "type": "basic",
                "orderSeq": 10,
                "properties": {
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },*
        "session1": {
        }
      }
    }
    
**Expected json data after structureInfo removal:** 
    
            {
              "header": {
                "method": "GET",
                "response": {
                  "type": "basic",
                  "status": "success"
                },
                "source": "#present"
              },
              "session": "abc",
              "body": {
                "session": {
                  "structuralComponent": {
                    "id": 2000,
                    "type": "tabs",
                    "orderSeq": 0,
                    "properties8i": {
                    }
                  }
                },
                "session1": {
                }
              }
        }
```

Comment: can you kindly simplify the example to not more than 5 lines instead of just dumping your existing code. I'll take a guess for now

Comment: I know the pain, apologies for that, But, I did not simply dumped my code and its not my actual code. Original code is about 4000 odd lines of json which I tried to put in most simplied form. But any ways, will try in future. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that instead of

```
showJson['body.structureInfo']
```

It should be something like:

```
showJson['body']['structureInfo']
```

And I don't know if `delete` can "nest" like this. Suggest you do this in multiple steps. Or you can create a new JSON out of the original and "leave out" some fields.

Comment: Thanks Peter! At least in above case delete showJson['body']['structureInfo'] worked. Earlier, I tried your suggestion like  "create a new JSON out of the original and "leave out" some fields.", this worked but for looking more robust solution, as some times I may not know, some json fields may be added/removed, in every case if   structureInfo  field present i need to remove using karate. Good time, thanks